# How to import Routes in the Spec

Tags: angular6, angular-routing

I have the following route defined in `app-routes.ts` as a separate module

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
...

const routes:Routes = [
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: New
    canActivate:[AuthGuard] 
  },
  {
    path:'list',
    component:List
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    component: SignupComponentComponent 
  },
  {
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch:'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component:HomepageContentComponentComponent 
  },
  { path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], //
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers:[]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

I am using the route in the `HomePageComponent`. How do I test the routing? I know I need to use `RouterTestingModule.` like follows:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)], //routes is undefined here
      declarations: [ HomepageContentComponentComponent,
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

But the `routes` variable defined as `const routes:Routes = ...` in `AppRoutingModule` isn't available here.

Question 1) How in my current setup, I can make `routes` visible in the `specs`

Question 2)I thought to create a separate file `myroutes.ts` which contains only the `routes` array so that I can use it in the specs but even that doesn't work. Why? ( something like the following)

```
my-route.ts
  const routes:Routes = [
    {...      ];
```

Why am I note able to use `routes` in `imports:[RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)]` when I created it in a sepafrate file?

Answer (score 0):

I should have exported the `routes` as `export const routes:Routes`